# How to refer to a filepath that is a named range in a cell in a macro code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if anyone knows how to correctly reference a named ranged that contains a file path to a workbook? I am wanting to refer to a named range as the filepath will change often, and I don't want to manually keep changing the code.

'Number of CCGs yet to have data:

```
    'Specify workbook, sheet and range to copy from
            Workbooks("201819 MASTER Consol Tool AA TEST.xlsb").Sheets("Summary").Range("I1").Copy

        'Specify workbook, sheet and range to copy into
         Workbooks("Macro.xlsm").Sheets("Key info").Range("D7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

So instead of providing the hard coded file path, I'd like to refer to a named range in the current workbook.

The named range for the first file path is: Consol
The named range for the second file path is: Current

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can refer to a Named Range, exactly the same way as a cell . `Range("D7")` would be `Range("Name")`

Comment: Unfortunately when I replace the file path with a named range, it doesn't work - I am wondering if this is because it's a file path it is trying to pick up?

Comment: No that can't be the case. Something else must be the problem

Comment: Below is the full code - do you (or anyone else) think you could help on how to incorporate the file path as a named range instead?

Comment: Sub Extract()
'Specify workbook, sheet and range to copy from
 Workbooks("201819 MASTER Consol Tool AA TEST.xlsb").Sheets("Summary").Range("K1").Copy

             'Specify workbook, sheet and range to copy into
                Workbooks("Macro.xlsm").Sheets("Key info").Range("D9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub

Comment: Add it in the Question. It's not readable in a Comment

Comment: you want to read this `201819 MASTER Consol Tool AA TEST.xlsb` from a cell  ?

Comment: Yeah - so I have tried adding in a cell reference or a named range, but it says "Run time error 9, subscript out of range" even though the named range is the exact same as the file path that is above.

Answer (score 0):

**See this way you can refer to a Named Range.**

```
Range("name").Value
```

[image]

**So your line:**

```
Workbooks("201819 MASTER Consol Tool AA TEST.xlsb").Sheets("Summary").Range("I1").Copy
```

**Will Become:**

```
Workbooks(Range("name").Value).Sheets("Summary").Range("I1").Copy
```

if you use the named range